Implementing Copy paste image to clipboard manager-JAVA
Basically, I am building my own custom keyboard in java and kotlin and want to implement the feature which is in gboard that is if I take any screenshot it appears on the clipboard manager. So far, I have read the docs and am using mediaStore but nothing helps and its returning my screenshot URI as null. Can you please tell me the right approach?


Have you read [ask] ?
